# How to bin data by thirds or quarters - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ranking-functions

I am working with a dataset that looks like the following:

```
|  Part | OpenDays |
|:-----:|:--------:|
| ABB52 |    203   |
| ABB85 |    52    |
| ABB88 |    365   |
| ABB26 |    311   |
| ABB75 |    288   |
| ABB92 |    98    |
| ABB36 |    113   |
| ABB37 |    77    |
| ABB73 |    297   |
```

I am ideally trying to group this data into bins (either into the top third percentile, middle third percentile, or bottom third percentile). It could be the case that we ultimately move to quarters.

I am trying to utilize the `PERCENT_RANK` function in OracleSQL but cannot figure out how to use it properly.

I am trying something like the following:

```
SELECT
  tblSO.Part,
  CASE
    WHEN OpenDays <= PERCENT_RANK(0.33) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OpenDays DESC) THEN 1
    ELSE NULL END AS OpenDaysGroup

FROM
  tblSO

GROUP BY
  tblSO.Part
```

But get the error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Ideally, my dataset would look like:

```
| Part  | OpenDays |
|-------|----------|
| ABB88 | 3        |
| ABB26 | 3        |
| ABB73 | 3        |
| ABB75 | 2        |
| ABB52 | 2        |
| ABB36 | 2        |
| ABB92 | 1        |
| ABB37 | 1        |
| ABB85 | 1        |
```

I have set up this [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea987b/1) for demonstration with example data.

How can I use `PERCENT_RANK` to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. At the end when you say "ideally, my **dataset** would look like" - do you mean "my **output** would look like..."? Also, if that is the output, is the second column the **bin number**, not **OpenDays**? And, what are your rules... are you trying to make the bins contain equal number of "open days" (as much as possible, and regardless of how many "parts" are in each bin), or are you trying to equalize the number of "parts" in each bin (no matter the open days)? The functions you mention work for the latter problem, not for the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I usually use brute force for this:

```
SELECT tblSO.Part,
       FLOOR( (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OpenDays DESC) - 1) * 3 /
              COUNT(*) OVER ()
            ) AS OpenDaysGroup
FROM tblSO;
```

Why?  First, the calculation is not very complicated.  More importantly, who can remember how ties are handled by the built-in functions.  For instance `NTILE()` -- which also does what you want -- puts ties in separate groups.  So will the above code.

However, if I want ties in the same group, I would just use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT tblSO.Part,
       FLOOR( (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY OpenDays DESC) - 1) * 3 /
              COUNT(*) OVER ()
            ) AS OpenDaysGroup
FROM tblSO;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea987b/5) is a SQLFiddle.

Comment: Getting `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected ` when trying to run on `SQLFIDDLE` for both options.

Comment: @JerryM. . . . The `GROUP BY` doesn't make sense for the query.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the OP the following question:  What is the main objective of the query? To assign "parts" to bins, in such a way that each bin contains equal numbers of **parts**, as much as possible - regardless of the total number of **open days** in each bin? Or is it to equalize, as much as possible, the total number of **open days** across the bins, even if that means some bins will receive more parts (but parts with fewer open days each)?  Clearly, the two objectives contradict each other; the two problems are different.

The OP hasn't answered yet. But the latter problem is interesting enough to deserve a solution either way.

**EDIT** *It seems that my question (posted as a comment under the original question) has been removed. Whoever did that has left no explanation. In any case, the question is reproduced above.*  **END EDIT**

Gordon Linoff offered a solution that equalizes the number of parts in each bin; in that solution (and problem statement, really) the "open days" count in each row in the input plays absolutely no role. This is the trivial problem (of the two possible interpretations).

The hard problem - of equalizing the sum of open days in each bin, as much as possible - can be solved by complete enumeration (consider ALL possible assignments, choose the best one), but that becomes impractical very quickly. One needs an algorithm, and one also likely needs to accept a solution that is "good enough", while being reasonably good but also practical (the query should complete in less than a year, say, for moderately large input datasets).

Here is such an algorithm, and then an implementation in Oracle SQL - using a recursive WITH clause, which requires Oracle version 11.2 or higher.

Start with three bins, and order the "parts" descending by "open days". Break ties by "open days" in any manner - that is unimportant, but ties must be broken. That's easy with the analytic `ROW_NUMBER()` function, in a preliminary subquery.

Keep track of total open days in each bin SO FAR. (Before we start, the total is zero in each bin.) At each step, take the next part (as ordered by `ROW_NUMBER()`) and assign it to the bin with the least then-current sum of open days. If there are ties, prefer bin 1, then bin 2, over the other bins.

Here is the query and the result - with the input data in a CTE (in the WITH clause) for testing.

```
with
  tblso (part, opendays) as (
    select 'ABB52', 203 from dual union all
    select 'ABB85',  52 from dual union all
    select 'ABB88', 365 from dual union all
    select 'ABB26', 311 from dual union all
    select 'ABB75', 288 from dual union all
    select 'ABB92',  98 from dual union all
    select 'ABB36', 113 from dual union all
    select 'ABB37',  77 from dual union all
    select 'ABB73', 297 from dual
  )
, prep (part, opendays, rn) as (
    select part, opendays, row_number() over (order by opendays desc) from tblso
  )
, r (part,  opendays, rn, bin, sum1, sum2, sum3) as (
    select  part, opendays, 1, 1, opendays, 0, 0
      from  prep
      where rn = 1
    union all
    select  p.part, p.opendays, p.rn,
            case when r.sum1 <= r.sum2 and r.sum1 <= r.sum3 then 1
                 when r.sum2 <= r.sum3                      then 2
                                                            else 3 end,
            case when r.sum1 <= r.sum2 and r.sum1 <= r.sum3 then r.sum1 + p.opendays 
                                                            else r.sum1 end,
            case when r.sum2 <  r.sum1 and r.sum2 <= r.sum3 then r.sum2 + p.opendays 
                                                            else r.sum2 end,
            case when r.sum3 <  r.sum1 and r.sum3 <  r.sum2 then r.sum3 + p.opendays 
                                                            else r.sum3 end
    from    prep p join r on p.rn = r.rn + 1
  )
select part, opendays, bin
from   r;
```

Output:

```
PART    OPENDAYS        BIN
----- ---------- ----------
ABB88        365          1
ABB26        311          2
ABB73        297          3
ABB75        288          3
ABB52        203          2
ABB36        113          1
ABB92         98          1
ABB37         77          2
ABB85         52          1
```

For comparison, here are the "part" counts and the "open days" sums for the solution in Gordon's answer, vs. the query in this answer:

**GL summary**

```
       BIN PART_COUNT TOTAL_OPENDAYS
---------- ---------- --------------
         0          3            973
         1          3            604
         2          3            227
```

**mathguy summary**

```
       BIN PART_COUNT TOTAL_OPENDAYS
---------- ---------- --------------
         1          4            628
         2          3            591
         3          2            585
```

Gordon's solution assigns three of the nine input parts to each of three bins, but the total opendays per bin range from 227 to 973. In my solution, one bin gets four parts, another gets only two; but the total opendays per bin range from 585 to 628 - a much tighter distribution.

While one cannot guarantee that, in general, the algorithm I described here will find the optimal solution (to be clear: to the **hard** problem), it is almost certain that it will find much better solutions than assigning equal number of "parts" to each bin in almost all cases.

Comment: Hello. I will test your answer and respond back with results or follow up questions. I believe this question is valuable to others. Thank you for the response @mathguy

Comment: @JerryM. - Deciding which interpretation of the problem is correct is a matter for the business users who requested your help with this. It's not for the IT department to decide as it wishes. (Similar questions are asked by users in the IT department itself, too - those who ask are then the "business users" who should decide, not the person who writes the SQL code.)

Comment: As indicated in the original post, it may be the case I need more than 3 bins and may need 4 (or another number).

I would assume to make that change, I change the `r` recursive query to include `sum4` or `sumx`, correct?

Comment: @JerryM. Yes, and make the other needed change.